# angular2 rxjs filter threads with input text

Tags: text, filter, angular, rxjs5, angular2-pipe

Hi I'm building a small stackoverflow-like forum and I'm trying to implement a simple text-filter for my threads-titles.

I've recently started learning about rxjs and pipes so this is what I came up so far with 2 issues

1. I'm not sure which method I should use to to parse the title, i'm currently using string.include() but it's not working correctly (e.g. if I type who, then "how" shows, if I type "how" then "who" shows...

**UPDATE: Sofar the major error seems to be that the pipe only receives the first letter...but no clue on what causes it.**

2. I'm using a pure pipe and the property gets passed to it via an subject,not sure if this is the best practice way...

https://plnkr.co/edit/VViLYFd5oFTwNqP9eoZi?p=preview

Thanks for help and suggestions

Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'dashboard-main',
  pipes:[FilterTitle],
  template:`
  <input type="text" id="title" [(ngModel)]="binding" (keyup)="trigger()">
  <h3>{{binding}}</h3>
  <hr>
  <h3>{{testText}}</h3>
<hr>
<ul>
<li *ngFor="#thread of threadlist | filterTitle:testText">{{thread.title}}</li>
</ul>
  `
})
export class DashboardMainComponent implements OnInit{

  binding:string='Input';
  text$:Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
  testText:string="";

  ngOnInit():any {
    this.text$.debounceTime(500).distinctUntilChanged().subscribe( text => this.setText(text))
  }

  trigger(){
    this.text$.next(this.binding);
  }

  setText(text:string){
    console.log(text);
    this.testText = text;
  }

  threadlist=[
    {
      title:'Who are you?'
    },
     {
      title:'How are you?'
    },
     {
      title:'Where are you?'
    }
    ]
}
```

Pipe

```
@Pipe({
  name:'filterTitle',

})

export class FilterTitle implements PipeTransform{
    transform(array:any[], [search]):any {
      if(search ===''){
        return array
      }
      return array.filter(thread => {
        return thread.title.includes(search)
      })
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "but it's not working correctly" mean exactly? The Plunker seems to work fine.

Comment: if I type 'how' then 'Who are you?' and 'Where are you?' are shown, if I type "areasdlkfasdf" then some are shown,...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter declaration in the pipe was wrong. It should be

```
transform(array:any[], search):any {
```

instead of

```
transform(array:any[], [search]):any {
```

Since beta.16 pipes don't get an array or parameters passed anymore. Each value is passed as a distinctive parameter https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta16-2016-04-26

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/aQYnRkmKbIRo1Vptujjh?p=preview)

Comment: thanks for the hint!, what is the distinctive syntax? space, comma or semicolen?
transform(array:any[], arg1 arg2...):any {}
and in view?
{let item of items | pipe:arg1:arg2}

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. The first parameter is the value that is passed to the pipe and each subsequent parameter passed like `someVal | myPipe:param1:param2` can be accepted like `transform(array:any[], param1, param2):any {`

Comment: thanks what i was asking, so params will be separated with commas

Comment: Exactly, like in any other method with multiple parameters.